# Can I draw an end-of-proof box this way with \hrule and \vrule?

Tags: rules

Does this end-of-proof box look all right?

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\proofbox}{\vbox{\hrule height0.75pt\hbox{\vrule height1ex width0.75pt\hskip0.5em\vrule width0.75pt}\hrule height0.75pt}}

\begin{document}

This ends the proof.\quad\proofbox

\end{document}
```

You might not think it has the best shape or line thickness, but is there anything blatantly wrong with it? Somebody's telling me that, on their computer, the top and bottom edges are sticking out too far to the right in the PDF; but the sides all look perfectly flush in the PDF that I'm making at overleaf.com.

Comment: It looks flush to me, but why not just \square ?

Comment: Also most people expect it to be at the right edge of the text, and envs are generally better to use to add them instead of by hand.

Comment: Note in low resolution devices using a character from a font is likely to be more consistent as the system can use font hinting to ensure that things round to pixel boundaries in a consistent way. Rules on the other hand can show artifacts from rounding to the device pixels (as often seen with couloured tables losing thin rules)

Comment: Thanks. This is just a hypothetical example. I'm just trying to make sure there's nothing in that TeX definition that would be causing the sides of the box to be "off".